# Can Gas diffuse according to its partial pressure, not according to its concentration in gas mixture?

Tags: thermodynamics

by Raoult's law,

Partial pressure  =  total pressure  X  concentration(mole fraction)

In gas exchanging situation of 2 gas mixtures which are different in total pressure from each other(like higher temperature?) and include gas A of same concentration, each gas A in 2 mixtures will be the same in its concentration but different in partial pressure. Then, gas A will diffuse from high partial pressure to low partial pressure even though this diffusion is from low concentration to high concentration. Is this right??

Sorry for any misconceptions.

Comment: The problem is basically expansion of gas. You assumed in Q that gas A has the same molar fraction in both halves of the container. ...

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, diffusion occurs due to gradients in chemical potential.
One implication of this is that sometimes diffusion can occur from lower to higher concentration.
See, for example, [this nice class summary](http://www.eng.utah.edu/~lzang/images/lecture-3.pdf)

If the total pressure is different, the transport will also occur by fast flow convection instead of diffusion until total (mechanical) pressures are equal (unless [thermal transpiration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_transpiration) effects are significant).